# BCP export data which contains new-line character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, bcp

I am new to BCP utility, willing to export/import data from `SQL Server 2014 | compatibility level: 120` using BCP utility through the below command:

`bcp 'select * from <DB-name>.<schema-name>.<table-name>' queryout '/tmp/mssql_out.csv' -t, -C 'RAW' -a 32576 -U '<user-name>' -P '<password>' -S '<host>','<port>' -e '/tmp/error.mssql' -f '/tmp/format.mssql'`

Here one of the table columns (varchar) contains the **new-line** character as a value. Data is corrupted when I export it through the above command.

Comment: I recommend using a tool that allows for quote identifying your data, `bcp` doesn't have that feature. The alternative would be, if you know *which column(s)* can contain the line breaks, is wrap that column's value in double quotes, and escape any within its value.

Comment: Whilst [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) can import RFC 4180 style CSV files that include commas, quotes and line break characters in the data, the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) is not correspondingly smart enough to export data in that format. Consider using something more appropriate, such as the `Export-Csv` cmdlet in PowerShell.